# How to make a DIV take up the remainder of the page?

Tags: css, html, height

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div id='large_div'>
    blah.. blah.. blah..
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the `large_div` take up the rest of the page height?

Here is the CSS for the page:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; }
#large_div {
    /* ??? */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try setting a negative margin on the #large_div that was equal to the height of the h2.  Unfortunately this will not very solid code since that h2 height will change depending on text length and browser:

```
#large_div {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -1em; /* adjust to height of h2 */
}
```

A bit of jQuery would sort you out though:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#large_div').css({height: $(window).height() - $('h2').height()});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you basically want a table layout? This is one of the nastiest things in CSS. You might consider to fall back to old fashioned HTML tables, but if you don't care about [IE6/7 support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html), then you can also play around using `display` attributes of `table`, `table-row` and eventually `table-cell`.

Here's an SSCCE, copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3323454</title>
        <style>
            html { 
                height: 100%;
            }
            body { 
                display: table; 
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #large_div {
                display: table-row; 
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: pink;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div id="large_div">blah.. blah.. blah..</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again, this works in decent CSS2-adhering browsers only.

If all you want to achieve is to give the div a nice background, then there are nicer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body {height:100%;border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;}

#large_div {height:100%;margin:0px;}
```

Comment: This will give the DIV a height of 100% of its parent. Since the parent also has an <h2>, this will cause the page to expand to be larger than 100% of the window's height.

Comment: should've given the whole page in context then, and no, the div will take up 100% of the height and the html and body tags' heights, margins, and paddings will not interfere by adding

if you dont want the div to take up 100% of page make html,body {height:100%;} instead

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you're saying, but what I'm saying is that if the DIV has a height of 100%, it will be the same as the height of the page. And since the page has an H2 in it already, this will expand the page to be larger than 100% of the window.

Comment: George is right. The height will be relative to the parent element, regardless of which siblings there are already in. Run it yourself and see with your own eyes.

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the height of the top div (or h2 in this case), you might be able to try something like the following:

```
#topdiv { height:100px; }
#bottomdiv { height:100%; margin-bottom:-100px; bottom:0; }
```

Unfortunately, I can't test this from where I am right now, so this could be way off... But I believe I've used something similar to this before and it had a similar effect.

You may be able to find your solution - or at least a "good enough" solution, by playing around with those css properties...

Good luck!